# getItemViewType is not working as supposed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I tried to create a RecycleView for more Objects to display but for some reason funcion getItemViewType doesnt work or it might work but selects second option only because the output from onCreateViewHolder is always the first option.

This is the funcion in the method

```
private void insertObjects(){
            items.add(new Object(1));
            items.add(new Object(2));

            mMultiAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This is the Adapter
Even if I change first if of getItemViewType to if(position % 2 == 0) > it will output the same option everytime

```
public class MultiAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    public MultiAdapter(List<Object> Parts) { this.items = Parts; }

    public static class ChestViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
TextView second_segment;

        private ChestViewHolder( View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            second_segment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.segment_tuesday);

        }
public static class BackViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView first_segment;

        private BackViewHolder( View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            first_segment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.segment_monday);

        }
public static class DefaultViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView default_segment;

        private DefaultViewHolder( View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            default_segment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.segment_sunday);
        }
    }
    private static int ITEM_TYPE_C_T;
    private static int ITEM_TYPE_S_B;

    private List<Object> items = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder Holder, int position) {non code inside of this method}

    @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            if (items.get(position).getId()== 1){ 
                return ITEM_TYPE_C_T;
            }
            else if(items.get(position).getId()== 2){
                return ITEM_TYPE_S_B;
            }else {
                return ITEM_TYPE_C_T;//(DEFAULT)
            }
        }

    @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

    @NonNull
        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

            if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_S_B){
                View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.segment_nOne,parent,false);
                return new BackViewHolder(view);
            } else if(viewType == ITEM_TYPE_C_T) {
                View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.segment_nTwo,parent,false);
                return new ChestViewHolder(view);
            }else{
                //to prevent crash on null
                View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.nOne,parent,false);
                return new DefaultViewHolder(view);
            }
        }
```

This is the object

```
public class Object {
    private int id;

    public Object(){ }

    public Object(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Could you plz show full class "Object.java" ? I think main issue is in it. Recycleview code looks like good

Comment: interesting, I don't understand why it doesn't working. May be problem inside viewholders... Could you please add/update full recyclerViewAdapter code with ViewHolder's?

Comment: I tried to make it as readable as possible, hope you will find something @EvstropovV

Comment: I suggest renaming your `Object` class as it can be easily confused with `java.lang.Object` class which is a superclass of all objects in java.

Comment: I renamed my `Object` to `myObject`as you have suggested but it didn't solve the problem. @Pawel

Comment: Issue is that both variables  ITEM_TYPE_C_T and ITEM_TYPE_S_B equals 0. You must set value to them:  'private static int ITEM_TYPE_C_T = 1;
    private static int ITEM_TYPE_S_B = 2;'